# What is the physical path of Odoo webserver?

Tags: webserver, odoo, openerp-8

I'm building a custom odoo module that will be using several Javascript libraries. 
I need to add references to those libraries (local references) but I don't know exactly where to place those libraries and how to refer to their location.

What I tried:
- I created the new module and placed the libraries inside the module directory but it didn't work.
- I also placed the libraries in the home directory of odoo.

As I understand, the problem would be solved if I could get the default directory of the webserver that odoo runs on.

Comment: Can you write more specific about what directory you put the Javascript library? You should put the file inside 'static' folder in your module and put reference inside __openerp__.py

Comment: My problem is that I need to use HTTP controller and route it to a certain html page with javascript libraries (using @http.route). When I do this and create a page with many js library files, the page doesn't recognize any of those files as dealing with the webserver is different than dealing with the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

If module is using js files, then you must put these files inside your module. And still if you cant reach these files from your module its your technical error and you have to fix it yourself, also note that odoo has its js libraries already

Answer (score 0):

I found this page: [how to add css and js files in Openerp 7 / Odoo module](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-add-css-and-js-javascript-files-in-openerp-7-odoo-8-module-76719) maybe can help you.

Below is the content.

1. Store files correctly:
   CSS and JS files should be reside under 'static' directory in the module(the rest of subdirectory tree under 'static' is an optional convention):

   - static/src/css/your_file.css
   - static/src/js/your_file.js
2. Add files in manifest (v7.0) or in XML(v8.0)

   - Openerp v7.0 way is to add following entries in manifest (in **openerp**.py):
     ...
     'css': ['static/src/css/your_file.css'],
     'js': [static/src/js/your_file.js'],
     ...
   - Odoo v8.0 way is to add corresponding record in the XML:
     Add XML to the manifest (**openerp**.py):
     ...
     'data': [ 'your_file.xml'],
     ...
     Then add following record in 'your_file.xml':

   ```
   <data>
       <template id="assets_backend" name="your_module_name assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
           <xpath expr="." position="inside">
               <link rel='stylesheet' href="/your_module_name/static/src/css/your_file.css"/>
               <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module_name/static/src/js/your_file.js"></script>
           </xpath>
       </template>
   ....
   ....
   </data>
   ```